# Consulta procedimiento almacenado con dll de conexion

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, stored-procedure

quería ver si alguien me pudiese orientar un poco.
hice una DLL para una conexión a la base de datos, en donde tengo una función ShowDataByQuery(String query),

de forma normal realizo así las consultas:

```
dataGridView3.DataSource = con.ShowDataByQuery("SELECT * from Comuna as Co JOIN Region Re ON Re.IdRegion = Co.IdRegion");
```

y no tengo ningún problema, el tema que ahora necesito hacer la misma consulta, pero a través de un procedimiento almacenado, el cual ya lo realicé:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE ConsultaComuna 
    @IdRegion int,
    @Comuna nvarchar(128), 
    @InformacionAdicional xml
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Comuna, @InformacionAdicional FROM Comuna WHERE IdRegion = @IdRegion
END
GO
```

Pero no sé como realizar esa consulta al procedimiento almacenado,
si me pueden pasar alguna documentación que me sirva, que no he encontrado mucho con un dll de conexión.

gracias :)

Comment: si esa dll la hiciste vos, vas a tener que agregar un procedimiento donde le pases el nombre del SP a ejecutar y los parametros.. no termino de entender la pregunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la dll es tuya, podrias probar algo asi:

```
 public class dbConnect
 {
    private string _connString;
    private SqlConnection _sqlConn;

    public dbConnect()
    {
        this._connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ARB"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteSP(string strSP, Dictionary<string, string> listParams)
    {
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            this._sqlConn = new SqlConnection(this._connString);
            using (this._sqlConn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSP);
                cmd.Connection = this._sqlConn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                if (listParams != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in listParams)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + item.Key, item.Value);
                    }
                }
                da.Fill(ds);
                this._sqlConn.Close();
            }
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Así seria tu clase, con el método que recibe el nombre del sp y los valores.
Luego en el Form lo llamarías así:

```
            dbConnect db = new dbConnect();
            Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            param.Clear();
            param.Add("IdRegion", "1");
            param.Add("Comuna ", "Test");
            param.Add("InformacionAdicional ", xml.ToString());
            
            dataGridView3.DataSource = db.ExecuteSP("ConsultaComuna ", param);
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, Saludos!

Edit: Me di cuenta que di un ejemplo con Dictionary<string, string>, pero podrias cambiarlo a Dictionary<object, object> o Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> tanto cuando lo instancias como cuando lo recibis por parametro y en el foreach del KeyValuePair, entonces asi podras guardar todo tipo de valores en el dic.